# Localizing a .plist file (not settings or info.plist)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I need to localize a .plist file using some .strings files. This is not for the "main" strings in the app, nor is it for the "Settings.bundle" (I've already done those and they work OK). I simply have another .plist file that I need to match up a list of strings and translations. I've spent hours reading all the related answers but I can't get it to work.

I have my file "Something.plist" and I created a strings file "Something.strings" and localized the strings file. My plist is structured like:

```
Root - Dictionary
StringsTable - string - Something
  group - array
    item - dictionary
      someword1 - wordkey1
      someword2 - wordkey2
      ...
```

In code I call the method to load the Plist data and later read the items in the array, which I thought is supposed to read from my StringsTable = "Something.strings" from how I read the docs.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Something" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dictionaryFile = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
self.sandwichMenuCommandGroup = [dictionaryFile objectForKey:@"GroupName"];
```

I think that for every key "wordkey1" in my Something.strings file, that the pathForResource command would include the translated words. The more I read my question the more I see that maybe it's not going to do that. I really do not want to have to build 20 .plist files by hand by directly localizing the .plist itself.